# copy from html form and paste on outlook

Tags: asp.net, outlook

I want to build an application in which when I fill up a form it will copy the data and on a button click it will paste some of the data in outlook email body

Thanks

Comment: Please start trying to build this application and then come back to SO with specific problems.  You have asked no questions in your post.

Answer (score -1):

I am about to finish my webform site 
Issue : when I add small content (any type) to textarea and click on submit , it works !

But when i enter long multi line text in textarea it give me syntax error near s.

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data source=hidden;  initial catalog=dsatdata;  User id=sa; password=xxxxxx");
        con.Open();
        var query = "insert into escalationmatrix values ('" + lbl_case_number.Text + "','" + Request.Form["statust"].ToString() + "','" + Request.Form["status_summaryt"].ToString() + "', '" + Request.Form["impact_severityt"].ToString() + "', '" + Request.Form["next_stept"] + "', '" + Request.Form["root_causet"] + "','" + DateTime.Now + "')";

```
    // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [escalation] SET [Status] = '" + Request.Form["statust"].ToString() + "', [status_summary] = '" + Request.Form["status_summaryt"].ToString() + "', [impact_severity] = '" + Request.Form["impact_severityt"].ToString() + "', [next_step] = '" + Request.Form["next_stept"] + "', [root_cause] = '" + Request.Form["root_causet"] + "'  WHERE [Case_Number] = '" + lbl_case_number.Text + "'" , con);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);



    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`
```